# How to read individual values inside a JSON array/map in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter

In mu flutter code, I am getting a JSON data like below

```
{K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0xxxxxxxxxx: {-MMZHb3MzG_ABCD: true, -MMZHdIwN2x_EFGH: true}}
```

I want to read each records inside the array and print it like this

> `-MMZHb3MzG_ABCD`
>
> `-MMZHdIwN2x_EFGH`

Below is what I tried

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
List userChatRooms = map.values.toList();
print(userChatRooms[0]);
```

The output i get is as following

```
{-MMZHb3MzG_h1VGj3Aji: true, -MMZHdIwN2xwGs5w5-ul: true}
```

How can I get the output that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. what i have to do is just following.

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
List userChatRooms = map.values.toList();

              Map<dynamic, dynamic> map2 = userChatRooms[0];
              for (final name in map2.keys) {
                final value = map2[name];
                print('$name,$value'); 
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keys` getter on `first` element of your list converted map:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {"K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0xxxxxxxxxx": {"-MMZHb3MzG_ABCD": true, "-MMZHdIwN2x_EFGH": true}};

List userChatRooms = map.values.toList().first.keys.toList();

print(userChatRooms); // [-MMZHb3MzG_ABCD, -MMZHdIwN2x_EFGH]
print(userChatRooms[0]); // -MMZHb3MzG_ABCD
print(userChatRooms[1]); // -MMZHdIwN2x_EFG
```